# Check if a user has tweeted a specific text

Tags: .net, twitter

Is there a way to check if a user has tweeted a specific text (an exact match) by any Twitter API or .NET library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Twitter Search API**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)
- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Limitations

- The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.
- You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than about a week.
- Queries can be limited due to complexity. If this happens the Search API will respond with the error: {"error":"Sorry, your query is too complex. Please reduce complexity and try again."}
- Search does not support authentication meaning all queries are made anonymously.
- Search is focused in relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using the Streaming API instead.
- The near operator cannot be used by the Search API. Instead you should use the geocode parameter.

Recent Enhancements

- The user IDs returned in the Search API now match the user IDs utilized in the Twitter REST & Streaming APIs. You no longer need to maintain a mapping of "search IDs" and "real IDs."
- Use include_entities=true to have Tweet Entities included for mentions, links, media, and hashtags.
- in_reply_to_status_id and in_reply_to_status_id_str are now included with @replies, allowing you to know the replied-to status ID, which can be looked up using GET statuses/show/:id.

*(all of the above information was a dump from the first link in this post)*

Comment: is there a way to limit the results to a specific user?

Comment: yes, in the first link (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) scroll down about half way -- there is a table that displays `search operators` that shows all of the ways to modify a search

Comment: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=NOLES&from=TomahawkNation will run a `q`uery for tweets containing the text" NOLES" `from` "TomahawkNation"

Comment: You can also search for an exact match if you wrap the q value in quotes or %22. The url will look like ......?q=%22egypt%22&from=user_name

Answer (score 0):

No. Twitter API does 'debounce' [status updates](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) to prevent duplicates, but in terms of an API procedure to check for duplicates, none such exists.

I cant say for sure if there is some library out there that does this, but if there is, it will be doing it the long (only) way. Buy pulling pages of the target users tweets and doing your text analysis.

Comment: actually i don't want to check duplicates but probably it ends up in the same check :)